# Trying to create Interface with a method that uses a dynamic or anonymous type but an implementation that uses another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, interface, autofac

I am trying to do this in ASP.NET MVC. I want to have an interface

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    Task<IReadOnlyCollection<SomeTypeDTO>> aAssembleResponse(dynamic aSomeContext);
}
```

and on my implementation I want to have the following:

```
public class MyInterfaceService
{
    .... //unneeded code
    public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<SomeTypeDTO>> aAssembleResponse(
        SomeContext aSomeContext)
        return whatever     
}
```

Where I am initializing using *dynamic* in the interface but I am expecting another type(in this case *SomeContext*). My company is really big on DI and I'm really hitting the wall here. I can't *new* up SomeContext - nor use a constructor injection method here. And if I just leave it as *dynamic* it works absolutely fine - but Autofac goes insane and refuses to pass it.

Comment: Did you design `IMyInterface` or is that being forced on you. Using `dynamic` here sounds likely a really bad choice.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [generic interface.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwtft8ak.aspx)

Comment: Scott, the usage of dynamic was just a hack. Which is why I'm here - I knew it stank.

Comment: Okay, so here's the deal if I implement this with a generic, as in: aAssembleResponse(SomeContext aSomeContext) becomes aAssembleResponse<T>(T aSomeContext) everything works find until I try to access the DbSets inside aSomeContext or cast it over to SomeContext. I've tried Convert.ChangeType so far, any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I came up with the solution and I simply must blame the flu I'm getting over for it. But here is the very simple way this was solved.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
        Task<IReadOnlyCollection<SomeTypeDTO>> aAssembleResponse<T>(T aSomeContext);
}
```

and then my implementation

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<SomeTypeDTO>> aAssembleResponse<T>(T aSomeContext)
{
    var _SomeContext = (SomeContext)Convert.ChangeType(aSomeContext, typeof(SomeContext));
    return _SomeContext;     
}
```